# PHP imap pagination issue

Tags: php, email, gmail, imap

I am working on my code as I want to set the limit to 20 as I want to fetch 20 emails from gmail using imap.

When I try this:
 
<?php

```
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
ini_set('display_startup_errors', 1);
error_reporting(E_ALL);

// Load Composer's autoloader
require_once "Mail.php";
require_once "Mail/mime.php";
require_once('Mail/IMAPv2.php');

$username = 'myusername@gmail.com';
$password = 'mypassword';

$server = '{imap.gmail.com:993/imap/ssl/ssl}INBOX';
$inbox = imap_open($server, $username, $password);

$test = listMessages($inbox);

print_r($test);


function listMessages($inbox) {
    $page = 1;
    $per_page = 25;
    $sort = null;
    $limit = ($per_page * $page);
    $start = ($limit - $per_page) + 1;
    $start = ($start < 1) ? 1 : $start;
    $limit = (($limit - $start) != ($per_page-1)) ? ($start + ($per_page-1)) : $limit;
    $info = imap_check($inbox);
    $limit = ($info->Nmsgs < $limit) ? $info->Nmsgs : $limit;
    $msgs = '';
    $result = '';

    
     $perPage = 25;
     $start = $page == 1 ? 0 : $page * $perPage - ($perPage - 1);
     $order = 0;
     $by = SORTDATE;


     if (is_array($sort)) {
         $order = $this->sortBy['order'][$sort[0]];
         $by = $this->sortBy['by'][$sort[1]];
     }
     $sorted = imap_sort($inbox, $by, $order);

    $mails = array_chunk($sorted, $perPage);
    $mails = $mails[$page - 1];
    print_r($mails);

    return $return;
}
```

?>

It will fetch and display 77,500 emails which is too much so I need to reduce it, the easier way I would fetch the emails from the array that start from 0 to 24, 25 to 48.....etc.

Here is what I am trying to achieve:

```
page 1 of 5: 1-20 of 100
1: foo
2: bar
3: etc....

page 2 of 5: 21-40 of 100
21: foo
22: bar
23: etc...
```

Can you please show me an example I can fetch 20 emails from gmail using imap when I connect to my gmail inbox?

Thank you.

Comment: Something like this, maybe? https://stackoverflow.com/a/3946888/1427878